# Failing to register an application using unique Entity ID in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to implement SSO for an Oracle application using SAML method in Azure AD. There are 2 deployment instances of the same product that we need to configure in Azure AD. Registration of the 1st instance works fine, but registration of 2nd instance fails when we upload the SAML metadata file from the 2nd instance. That is due to the entityID clash with the 1st instance. Weirdly its EntityDescriptor has following format

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://<<login_uri>>" ID="xxx-xxx-xxx">
```

login_uri is same for the 1st instance but ID is different for each one.

I am not sure how to embed this `ID` in Azure AD during the configuration.

I tried to configure following in the field `"Entity ID"` in Azure AD but it didn't work

```
https://<<login_uri>>/?ID='xxx-xxx-xxx'
```

Comment: Entity ID is the uniquely identifies the application. I don't think you could add the 2nd app with the same Entity ID as the first one's. See details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications#step-1-edit-the-basic-saml-configuration

Comment: That's right. But my question is how do we configure ID. Or is this a product problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

```
https://<<login_uri>>#(id)
Or
https://<<login_uri>>#(index)
```

EG:

```
https://oracle.com/app#000-111-222
https://oracle.com/app#333-444-555
```

Or

```
https://oracle.com/app#1
https://oracle.com/app#2
```